$Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\{\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n|\varphi$ is an automorphism$\}$
Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. For group of divisors $\mathbb{Z}_n$ we label $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\{\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n|\varphi$ is an automorphism$\}$.
$1.$ I was able to prove that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is a group for an operation of composition of functions.
$2.$ I want to prove: if $p$ is prime, then for all $\overline{x}\in\{\overline{1},...,\overline{p-1}\}$ there exists a unique element of a group $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, which maps $\overline{1}$ in $\overline{x}$. Any idea where to even start here?
$3.$ I did not have any idea how to even start proving that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$.
$4.$ I need to show that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the statement from $3.$ does not hold in general. I want to somehow show that for $n=4$ this statement is false. I observe that in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ the order of elements $\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{2},\overline{3}$ are $1,4,2,4$ in that order. But how to justify that therefore $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_4)\ncong \mathbb{Z}_3$.

You can find the answers to all your questions here at this site. For $3$ there are many duplicates, e.g., this one. For $4$, see for example here. Since $\phi(4)=2$, we have that $Aut(C_4)\cong C_2$ is cyclic with $2$ elements.
